# Formatting and Sorting a Kendo Grid Column differently

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

For view purposes I am formatting the date values in my grid and that seems to be fine.
The problem is my column is also sortable and my custom date formatting is messing up the sorting. If I sort by real values from database, the sorting is fine but then I lose the ability of custom formatting the date for view purposes. So I wanted to see if there is a way to tell it format it like this but sort it some other way?

Here is how I format:

```
obj.Item.CustomFormattedDate = kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(obj.Item.RealDbDate, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'), 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt');
```

and then in my column definitions I setting my column to that field CustomFormattedDate  which is good for viewing but BAD for sorting. If I switch my field to be the actual `RealDbDate` values, then sorting becomes good but viewing becomes bad!

Comment: Have you tried to format in the column options([`format` option](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.format))? Its the best way I think.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing exactly what you're looking for. I'm using the ASP.NET Core wrappers for Kendo and set up the column like this:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.ShipDate).Format("{0:g}");
```

Ship Date in the model is a DateTime, the sorting works, but then I can make that format string any of those listed here https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/globalization/intl/dateformatting